# How do I execute an HTTP PUT in bash?

Tags: bash, put

I'm sending requests to a third-party API.  It says I must send an HTTP PUT to `http://example.com/project?id=projectId`

I tried doing this with PHP curl, but I'm not getting a response from the server.  Maybe something is wrong with my code because I've never used PUT before.  Is there a way for me to execute an HTTP PUT from bash command line?  If so, what is the command?

Comment: My I ask what you need to use PUT for? All I ever needed to use was GET and POST.

Comment: You can use curl for this purpose.

Check: http://superuser.com/questions/130009/how-can-i-do-a-http-put-with-wget

Comment: I need it because the API says i have to use it.  I have no idea why.  I'm just adding resources to a project

Comment: In REST design, a PUT is used to update an existing resource - see here if you want more info on the why: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: @asc99c PUT is not just for update, it is also for creating a resource when the client knows/sets the URI for the resource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With curl it would be something like

```
curl --request PUT --header "Content-Length: 0" http://website.com/project?id=1
```

but like Mattias said you'd probably want some data in the body as well so you'd want the content-type and the data as well (plus content-length would be larger)

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to only use bash it actually has some networking support.

```
 echo -e "PUT /project?id=123 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: website.com\r\n\r\n" > \
   /dev/tcp/website.com/80
```

But I guess you also want to send some data in the body?

Answer (score 0):

Like Mattias suggested, Bash can do the job without further tools. If you want to send data, you have to preset at least "Content-length". With variables "host", "port", "resource" and "data" defined, you can do a HTTP put with

```
echo -e "PUT /$resource HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $host:$port\r\nContent-Length: ${#data}\r\n\r\n$data\r\n" > /dev/tcp/$host/$port
```

I tested this with a Rest API and it workes fine.